# How to create multiple components with same logic or 1 component with multiple templates?

Tags: angular, angular8

I built a header row component for table-styled data in a report that allows multi-column sorting.  It's pretty simple: one property, two functions and an @Output() to let the parent component know when the order has changed.

I'd like to use now use that component in all of the other reports I have - every one will have the same logic, but they'll each have a different display.

I know than I can add an @Input() for reportType and then *ngSwitch code in my template, but I'd love to find a way to actually isolate the HTML for each header into it's own file (possibly with it's own SCSS file too) without creating a bunch of components with exactly the same logic.

That logic is included below just for fun.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sort-row',
  templateUrl: './sort-row.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sort-row.component.scss']
})
export class SortRowComponent {

  sortOrder: string[] = [];

  @Output() sortChanged: EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter<string[]>();

  constructor() {}

  sortingBy(field, dir?) {
    if (dir) {
      if (dir === 'desc') {
        field = '-' + field;
      }
      return this.sortOrder.indexOf(field) !== -1;
    } else {
      return this.sortOrder.indexOf(field) !== -1 || this.sortOrder.indexOf('-' + field) !== -1;
    }

  }

  toggleSortCol(col, evt) {

    const ascIdx = this.sortOrder.indexOf(col);
    const descIdx = this.sortOrder.indexOf('-' + col);

    if (!evt.shiftKey) {

      if (ascIdx !== -1) {
        this.sortOrder = ['-' + col];
      } else if (descIdx !== -1) {
        this.sortOrder = [col.replace('-', '')];
      } else {
        this.sortOrder = [col];
      }

    } else {

      if (ascIdx !== -1) {
        this.sortOrder[ascIdx] = '-' + col;
      } else if (descIdx !== -1) {
        this.sortOrder[descIdx] = col.replace('-', '');
      } else {
        this.sortOrder.push(col);
      }
    }

    this.sortChanged.next(this.sortOrder);
  }
}
```

Comment: Create a new component. Extend the one that has a logic and provide new component with a template

Comment: Is the different reports type has CSS changes only or has difference in html elements and CSS too?

Comment: @Sergey - that's exactly what I was looking for, and so simple I can't believe I didn't think of it.  Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanElSayed - they're all based on the same look and feel but each might have some specific CSS.  Doesn't matter with Sergey's solution, because I can use `styleUrls: ['../shared/generic.scss', './component-specific.scss']` to have a default style set that gets overridden when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you want to have several components using same logic while having different markups you neeed to simply create another component. Extend the one with the logic. And use all the benefits of OOP (inherited props and methods).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add new `@Input() customCSSClasses: Object` to your generic component and pass the new CSS classes from host component and use `ngClass` on selected elements to apply those custom classes (you need to add those custom classes in your global `styles.css` file.)

For example:

```
// Host component.html
<sort-row [customCSSClasses]="{input: 'dark-input', select: 'dark-lg-select'}" 
          // the other config
></sort-row>


// sort-row component.ts
@Input() customCSSClasses?: Object;

// sort-row component.html
<input [ngClass]="customCSSClasses?.input ? customCSSClasses?.input : 'default-input'">
<select [ngClass]="customCSSClasses?.select ? customCSSClasses?.select : 'default-select'"></select
```

Comment: Thanks very much but in my case, I want to make it so that the HTML and CSS for each table header could be completely different in structure and style, yet still come from the same base look & feel.